# Typical room activity is missing for one room in chat lobby

Tags: support, bug, chat

I just noticed that one room in [MSE chat domain](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=all&sort=active) doesn't have the "Typical room activity" widget:

[image: rooms list with one room missing the typical room activity graph]

The Trashcan room doesn't have the graph at all. Why is that?

Comment: Perhaps the activity is below a certain trigger. Looking at the logs of that room recently only one message a week was posted to keep the room alive.

Comment: I guess Luuklag is right, I have another such room on chat.meta (one message a week) and one on chat.se as well that are both lacking the same graph.

Comment: @Luuklag  yeah, makes sense. Need a dev to tell the threshold, or someone with enough time to look in enough such low activity rooms to reach a decent guess. :)